# How can I create a function in R that calculations across rows?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks similar to this:

| Patient ID | Unit Type | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | ABC | Returned |
| 1234 | ABC | Returned |
| 1234 | ABC | Returned |
| 1234 | ABC | Returned |
| 1234 | ABC | Transfused |
| 1234 | DEF | Transfused |
| 1234 | DEF | Transfused |
| 1234 | DEF | Transfused |
| 1234 | GHI | Transfused |

Table Code:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Patient_ID = c("1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", 
"1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234"), Unit_Type = c("ABC", 
"ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "GHI"), Status = c("Returned", 
"Returned", "Returned", "Returned", "Transfused", "Transfused", 
"Transfused", "Transfused", "Transfused")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I want my output to look like this (preferably in a new dataframe):

| Patient ID | ABC_Returned | ABC_Transfused | DEF_Tranfused | GHI_Transfused |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 1 |

How can I create a function that would automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)


df <- structure(list(Patient_ID = c("1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", 
                              "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234", "1234"), Unit_Type = c("ABC", 
                                                                                     "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "GHI"), Status = c("Returned", 
                                                                                                                                                         "Returned", "Returned", "Returned", "Transfused", "Transfused", 
                                                                                                                                                         "Transfused", "Transfused", "Transfused")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -9L))  
df2 <- df %>% 
      mutate(unit_stat = paste(Unit_Type, Status, sep = "_")) %>% 
      count(Patient_ID, unit_stat) %>% 
      tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = "Patient_ID", names_from = unit_stat, values_from = n)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  count(Patient_ID, Unit_Type, Status) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(Unit_Type, Status), values_from = n)
```

result

```
# A tibble: 1 × 5
  Patient_ID ABC_Returned ABC_Transfused DEF_Transfused GHI_Transfused
  <chr>             <int>          <int>          <int>          <int>
1 1234                  4              1              3              1
```